# slideshow in tabbed navigation

Tags: javascript, html, performance, slideshow

I want to have a slideshow in a tabbed navigation, I'm looking for a good slideshow script to integrate. There will be 6 tabs with 20 to 30 pictures slideshow in each, around 150 pictures in total.

All of the elements involved (tabs and slider instances) are marked as `<ul>` elements. I'm considering [Responsive Slides](http://responsiveslides.com/), it seems a good script, simple and light enough to do the job, however I'm concerned about the practical aspects:

- I will have a really large html file with all the content, such file
  will be difficult to maintain
- With such an amount of information the page will probably load slowly

Do you think there is a better, leaner way to build this?

Comment: That's not exactly the kind of question to post here.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: sorry about it but can you explain why this is off topic? I've looked at the help pages and I don't see any reason for your rejection

Comment: I'm not rejecting anything. I just pointed out that this kind of 'pool' is not allowed here.